# Can't access a variable inside a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables

So i defined two variables inside a function and made those variables global. However, when i try to access them outside a function, the program returns: "NameError: name 'mon_price' is not defined".

Here is the code for reference:

```
def seq_1():
    global mon_price, sun_price
    mon_price = int(input("Enter the selling price per turnip on monday morning: "))
    sun_price = int(input("Enter the sale's price per turnip on sunday: "))


x = mon_price / sun_price
```

Comment: You should initialise variable before function

Comment: Did you actually call the function?

Comment: You would need to call the function for those variables to become defined. Just because you wrote them somewhere once doesn't mean they automatically globally exist. But this is really a bad habit to get into, `return` values from functions instead!

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to call the function for your globals to be defined. But you actually don't need globals here (hint: you almost never need globals):

```
def seq_1():
    mon_price = int(input("Enter the selling price per turnip on monday morning: "))
    sun_price = int(input("Enter the sale's price per turnip on sunday: "))
    return mon_price, sun_price


def main():
   mon_price, sun_price = seq_1()
   x = mon_price / sun_price
   print("x = {}".format(x))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```